# Чем различаются указатели в Си от ссылок в C#?

Tags: c#, c

Верно ли, что указатели в Си аналогичны ссылочным типам в C#?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Концептуально -- да. Они решают задачу указания на объект. Но есть различия в реализации.

Указатели содержат адрес. Ссылки -- это, по сути, абстракция, которая ничего не говорит о своем значении (хотя по факту, CLR в них тоже помещает адрес).

Cсылка в C# всегда ссылается на валидный объект или равна `null`, указатель же может указывать в случайную область памяти. (спасибо за комментарий @VladD)

Кроме того, указатели С "статичны", а объект в дотнете может быть перемещен сборщиком мусора, т.е. ссылки изменяют свое значение.

Из этого факта вытекает еще одно отличие: в случае с указателями возможно безопасно делать арифметику (например, обращаться к i-му элементу массива, имея указатель на массив и зная размер элемента), в случае со ссылками -- нет.

В C# также существуют указатели. Они эквивалентны указателям в С.

Comment: Ещё одно концептуальное отличие в том, что ссылка в C# не бывает «висящей» или указывать в случайную область памяти, она всегда ссылается на валидный объект или равна `null`.

Comment: @VladD - Вы не пробовали обращаться к ссылочным членам класса в файналайзере :)?

Comment: @Igor: Да, это отдельная вещь. Но в любом случае по ссылке будет объект, хоть и финализированный. Вопрос консистентного состояния не управляется языком.

Comment: @VladD спасибо, добавил в ответ.

Answer (score 5):

Позвольте я на простом примере объясню слова **andreycha**:

> Указатели содержат адрес. Ссылки -- это, по сути, абстракция, которая ничего не говорит о своем значении

Допустим, имеется человек по имени Василий Пупкин, проживающий по адресу Ленина, 1. Его адрес является *указателем*. А понятие "дом Васи" является *ссылкой*. Можно сказать: "Едем на вечеринку в доме Васи", без точного указания адреса.

Если Василий теперь переедет на улицу Леннона, 2, то *адрес* изменится и, соответственно, должен изменится *указатель*. Меж тем *ссылка* "дом Васи" останется по-прежнему валидной.

Answer (score 0):

В дополнение к другим ответам. Кроме небезопасных указателей, в C# есть другой аналог указателям в C - это переменные, объявленные с ключевым словом ref:

```
int a = 1;
ref int alias = ref a;
Console.WriteLine($"(a, alias) is ({a}, {alias})");  // output: (a, alias) is (1, 1)

a = 2;
Console.WriteLine($"(a, alias) is ({a}, {alias})");  // output: (a, alias) is (2, 2)

alias = 3;
Console.WriteLine($"(a, alias) is ({a}, {alias})");  // output: (a, alias) is (3, 3)
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/declarations#reference-variables

Answer (score -1):

Хотел было докоментировать ответ andreycha, но потом подумал что лучше запостить отдельный ответ.

Начнем с того что понятием указателя(pointer) в С/С++ является адрес обьекта в оперативной памяти и представляет собой следующий синтаксис:

```
int x;
int *y = &x; // От любой переменной можно взять адрес при помощи операции взятия адреса "&". Эта операция возвращает указатель
int z = *y; // Указатель можно разыменовать при помощи операции разыменовывания "*". Это операция возвращает тот объект, на который указывает указатель
```

то есть перед названием стоит звездочка.

Так же есть ссылка (reference)

```
int x;
int &y = x;
int z = y;
```

Ссылки — это +- то же самое, что и указатели, но с другим синтаксисом и некоторыми другими важными отличиями. Они там работают вместе и дополняют друг друга: через указатель можно узнать значение по ссылке в С/С++.

В C# есть так же указатели и ссылки. Синтаксис указателя это такая же звездочка и применяется точно так же как и в Си/Си++ (это считается небезопасным кодом и нужно в настройках проэкта поставить галочку "Allow unsafe code" и использовать модификатор метода unsafe). И  так же возможна неявная передача ссылки с использованием ключевого слова `ref`, вместо &. Хотя ref в целом используется несколько по-другому в шарпе, чем & в С++ и в реализации, соответственно, отличается.

пример использования `ref` в шарпе:

```
public void SomeMethod(ref int a)
{
    a = 5;
    //здесь а==5 как внутри метода так и извне
}

var a =1;

SomeMethod(ref a);
```

Я бы не сказал бы, что указатели/ссылки в Си являются аналогом ссылочного типа в C#. Появление понятия ссылочных типов -- это просто следствие выбранной реализации, **но не аналог**. Прямыми аналогами же являются лишь перечисленные выше способы задвать указатели/референсы.

**А бездумное использование ссылочных типов напрямую как аналог -- это плохая практика. Например, если ты знаешь что в методе будет изменятся переданный параметр `List<T> someList` -- тебе нужно обязательно дописать `ref List<T> someList`, даже, не смотря на то, что это и так ссылочный тип и передавать ссылку на ссылочный тип, вроде как, безсмысленно.** Но это имеет смысл, ведь ты можешь нечаянно обмануть другого программиста или же самого себя в будущем.

А во всем остальном я согласен с ответом andreycha и дополнением VladDа.
То есть:

- указатели С "статичны", а объект в дотнете может быть перемещен сборщиком мусора, т.е. ссылки изменяют свое значение.
- И что ссылка в C# не бывает «висящей» или указывать в случайную область памяти, она всегда ссылается на валидный объект или равна null

Comment: вот только значения ref не передаются по ссылке (по крайней мере на уровне il). Они передаются по значению, но в обе стороны - т.е. запихиваются в стек перед вызовом метода, и достаются из стека после вызова. edit:(на самом деле нет)

Comment: @PashaPash , я только что проверил твои слова. ДО окончания метода с референсом оригинальная "а" уже имеет значение 5. Можешь проверить сам :) Я, конечно, допускаю что в релиз билде это может работать по-другому. Есть какие-то ссылки подтверждающие твои слова? А то на практике на дебаге я вижу поведение противоположное описаному тобой.

Comment: я не про теорию и практику, я про механизм передачи. "передача указателя" подразумевает что вы явно берете адрес переменной и передаете именно *адрес* как параметр. а при вызове через ref передачи адреса может и не происходить. в спеке все это описано в терминах "storage location". (т.е. она реально передача адреса скорее всего происходит, но это последствия оптимизации кода jit-ом -  т.е. особенности реализации). ref в C# - это аналог reference (&) из C++. А не указателей.

Comment: Возможно и так, я не на столько близко знаком с C++ :) Ответ писался опираясь на практический опыт работы с С# в первую очередь :) Так сказать, что вижу, то и пишу, а по поведению в шарпе я вижу что реф является, фактически, аналогом ссылки, только безопаснее в использовании :)

Comment: Да, просто в C++ ссылки и указатели - это разные вещи. И ref - это прямой аналог именно параметра-ссылки (только безопасный, с необходимостью писать ref в месте вызова), а не аналог указателя. (скорее всего пишущие на ++ минусуют за то, что вы их вместе смешали :)

Comment: @PashaPash вообще-то на уровне il-кода ref-типы являются именно что аналогами указателя

Comment: @PashaPash все отличие - в том, что их складывать нельзя... Или просто я не видел таких операций.

Comment: @PavelMayorov да, чуть недосомотрел - там с ними работа идет через Ldloca. Но тем не менее - это просто способ два разных имени для одного storage - а не способ получить адрес и работать с ним как с адресом.

Comment: @PashaPash указатель в стандартах Си/С++ тоже не в терминах адреса определяется

Comment: @PavelMayorov да, там указатель - это тип (сompound type вроде бы), как и reference. А в C# ref - не тип.

Comment: @PashaPash но при этом в CLR ref - это таки тип. И в новом C# его тоже хотят типом сделать.

Comment: @PavelMayorov да, но при этом его аналогом в C++ будет reference, а не pointer. Т.е. ссылка есть, но прямых манипуляций над адресом - нет.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56387/discussion-between-pashapash-and-pavel-mayorov).

Comment: В си нет ссылок.

Comment: Передача ссылочного типа в качестве параметра без ключевого слова ref означает, что назад будет возвращён тот же самый объект. Использование ref даёт возмодность подменить объект в вызываемом методе. например void Foo(ref string s) => s += "!";