# Великий и могучий new и что он там возвращает

Tags: c#

Недавно задал вопрос по-поводу передачи параметров в метод и всё что хотел узнать так это каким таким образом метод при передачи параметров по значению получает копии аргументов(для себя я подумал что за кадром выполняется операция присваивания аргумента(то что передали при вызове метода) параметру(то что указано в методе при его реализации)). После тех ответов решил искать что вообще происходит когда мы условно имея класс Car создаём его объект при помощи выражения Car c1 = new Car();
Зная что конструктор - это метод который вызывается при создании объекта и его имя совпадает с именем класса, и также он ничего не возвращает я начал думать что тогда  вообще хранится в этой переменной? В итоге копошась ещё и в новом для себя источнике Джеффри Рихтера я напоролся на вот такую формулировку:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И теперь хотелось бы задать вопрос я совсем рехнулся или в соответствии с этим(как я понял возвращается адрес объекта в памяти) получается так что ссылка и указатель это вроде как одно и тоже, а вроде как и нет ибо копаясь у себя в памяти и конспектах с университета я вспомнил что указатель - это переменная хранящая в себе адрес другой переменной(и можно не только указывать на переменную), а в итоге теперь после прочтения того абзаца у Рихтера я словил полный абзац и теперь не вижу никакой разницы между указателем и ссылкой. ПАМАГИТЕ

Comment: Откройте для себя IL коды и смотрите, что там творится.

Comment: формально определения и указателя и ссылки зависят от конкретного языка в котором они применяются.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/646876/184217

Comment: Судя по C++ CLR .NET на каждый чих выделяется память, так что с оптимизацией можно расслабиться.